# VBA - Set up a 2D array in VBA with random cells filled with color

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I need to set up a 2D array and randomly fill a certain amount of cells in it with color, as if the array is a container and the cells are molecules. After that I need to perform actions on them. The code I tried was:

```
Sub Insert_Molecules()

Dim Molecules() As Integer

Dim m As Integer, n As Integer
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

m = 10
n = 10

ReDim Molecules(1 To m, 1 To n) As Integer
For i = 1 To m
For j = 1 To n
Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

But what I figured out is that in that case, even if I don't set up an array, it would fill the whole range with color. But I need to fill them randomly *within* the array - I tried the **Rnd** function but I don't really know how to use it correctly and it didn't work.

What I tried was

```
Molecules(i * Rnd, j * Rnd) = Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

I just think I'm off point here and I'm clueless.
I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Are there any constraints on the randomness?  For example, could it randomly color 0 cells, and in another run randomly color every cell?

Comment: Let's say that I need to set up a certain amount of cells to be filled - it has to be a dynamic code as the user chooses the size of the array and the number of molecules to fill - but that's another issue, first I need to figure out how to even fill cells randomly. Let's say that within a 10x10 array I need to fill 3 molecules just as an example

Comment: `Molecules(i * Rnd, j * Rnd) = Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)` doesn't act like you think it will, if you're coming from most languages. In VBA, stringing together a bunch of = operators doesn't do a bunch of assignments. This is because the = operator does both assignment and equality check (vs languages that use ==). So what you're getting in that statement is `Molecules(i * Rnd, j * Rnd) = (True or False, Is the cell interior equal to Red?)`

Comment: Another thing to note is that `Rnd` is not exactly random either. Also, what is the point of the array `Molecules`? it appears you do nothing with that, and that you are really trying to work with a range of cells.

Comment: Mikegrann, the thing is I used the Rnd function to get a random number, I'm just not sure how to randomly fill cells - actually that code worked for me somehow filling the whole range in black, when my RGB is red, odd enough

Comment: Kyle, so is there another way to somehow randomize a range? I wanted to assign the filling into the array but it doesn't work because of the For loop so it does nothing - what I explained was that I need to fill the cells within the array but I don't know how to do that if it's not numbers

Comment: Use `Randomize` before your `Rnd` call to change the seed that gets passed to `Rnd`. Just entirely drop the `Molecules()` array. Check out [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/rnd.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim lWidth As Long
    Dim lHeight As Long
    Dim lMolecules As Long
    Dim lArea As Long
    Dim lRandom As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim sCells As String
    Dim sRandom As String
    Dim rMolecules As Range

    'Get width of container
    lWidth = Int(Application.InputBox("Provide width of container (must be a positive integer)", "Width", 10, Type:=1))
    If lWidth < 1 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid with [" & lWidth & "] provided.  Width must be a positive integer.  Exiting."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Get height of container
    lHeight = Int(Application.InputBox("Provide Height of container (must be a positive integer)", "Height", 10, Type:=1))
    If lHeight < 1 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid with [" & lHeight & "] provided.  Height must be a positive integer.  Exiting."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Get number of molecules to randomly fill within container
    lMolecules = Int(Application.InputBox("Provide Molecules of container (must be a positive integer)", "Molecules", 10, Type:=1))
    If lMolecules < 1 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid with [" & lMolecules & "] provided.  Molecules must be a positive integer.  Exiting."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    lArea = lWidth * lHeight

    'Populate string of cells that make up the container so they can be chosen at random
    For i = 1 To lHeight
        For j = 1 To lWidth
            sCells = sCells & "|" & Cells(i, j).Address
        Next j
    Next i
    sCells = sCells & "|"

    'Color the molecules at random
    For i = 1 To WorksheetFunction.Min(lMolecules, lArea)
        Randomize
        lRandom = Int(Rnd() * lArea) + 1
        sRandom = Split(sCells, "|")(lRandom)
        Select Case (i = 1)
            Case True:  Set rMolecules = Range(sRandom)
            Case Else:  Set rMolecules = Union(rMolecules, Range(sRandom))
        End Select
        sCells = Replace(sCells, "|" & sRandom & "|", "|")
        lArea = lArea - 1
    Next i

    rMolecules.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

End Sub
```

Comment: That's a fantastic code, thank you very much. So I do not need to use an array for that? Because the matrix (the array) needs to have a size, and when I will move the molecules they mustn't trespass the borders set with the user's choice.

Comment: @Toffes, no array necessary here. The code above ensures the borders aren't crossed. 

tigeravatar - What is the benefit of writing the cells to a string and pulling a random index of split? I just never would have thought of using this method.

Comment: @Kyle The benefit is that it ensures the random molecules can never be in the same cell.

Comment: Thought that might be the case, but didn't want to think that hard :). Thanks for the reply. Seems like a scripting dictionary could be used to much the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

This will randomly fill between 1 and 100 cells within the first 10 rows and 10 columns of the active sheet in the workbook you are using.

```
Sub Insert_Molecules()

Dim Molecules() As Integer

Dim m As Integer, n As Integer
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim NumOfTimes as Integer

Randomize
NumOfTimes  = Int ((100 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)

For i = 1 to NumOfTimes
    Randomize
    Cells(Int ((10 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1),Int ((10 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)).Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0)
Next i   

End Sub
```

Comment: Kyle, the code works great, finally it randomizes the cells. My question though is how do I fill a certain amount of random cells? Like if I want to fill only 3 cells now, how do I do that?

Comment: Istead of what is above for `NumOfTimes`, use `NumOfTimes = 3` and it will fill in 3 cells.