# VBA - check for duplicates while filling cells through a loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops, duplicates

I am writing a VBA code that goes through a defined matrix size and filling cells randomly within its limits.

I got the code here from a user on stackoverflow, but after testing it I realized that it does not fit for avoiding duplicate filling, and for instance when filling 5 cells, I could only see 4 cells filled, meaning that the random filling worked on a previously filled cell.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
Dim lRandom As Long
Dim sCells As String
Dim sRandom As String
Dim rMolecules As Range
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim lArea As Long


lArea = 400 '20x20
'Populate string of cells that make up the container so they can be chosen at random
For i = 1 To 20
    For j = 1 To 20
        sCells = sCells & "|" & Cells(i, j).Address
    Next j
Next i
sCells = sCells & "|"

'Color the molecules at random
For i = 1 To WorksheetFunction.Min(5, lArea)
    Randomize
    lRandom = Int(Rnd() * 400) + 1
    sRandom = Split(sCells, "|")(lRandom)
    Select Case (i = 1)
        Case True:  Set rMolecules = Range(sRandom)
        Case Else:  Set rMolecules = Union(rMolecules, Range(Split(sCells, "|")(lRandom)))
    End Select
    sCells = Replace(sCells, "|" & sRandom & "|", "|")
    lArea = lArea - 1
Next i

rMolecules.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
```

Using this same exact code which works perfectly, WHAT can I insert and WHERE do I do that so that the code would check if a cell is previously already filled with a string or a color?

I feel as though this code I'm looking for should be right before

```
rMolecules.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
```

But I'm not sure what to type.

**EDIT**
From the comments I realized that I should be more specific.
I am trying to randomly fill cells with the blue color (.ColorIndex = 5), but what I need to check first is if the randomizing hadn't marked a cell twice, so that for instance in this case, if I want to mark 5 different cells, it marks only 4 of them because of a duplicate and thus fills only 4 cells with the blue color. I need to avoid that and make it choose another cell to mark/fill.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Besides your main question, you should remove `Randomize` from the loop, and even from the entire function. It only needs to be used once -- preferably when the workbook gets opened. If you use `Randomize` in a loop -- you'll be getting random value from a set of 256 values -- it is a weird bug that has been there since the beginning of VBA.

Comment: I must say I don't fully understand what you are trying to do. You're looking for a way to fill cells with random colors but don't want a color to be duplicate?

Comment: @Spurious: I'm looking for a way to fill cells randomly with a certain color (blue in this case), but before it fills the cell, it should check if the randomizing hadn't marked a cell twice - meaning that when I fill it with .ColorIndex = 5, it won't fill the same cell again

Comment: Would the statement `.ColorIndex = 5` be true if it wasn't filled before? I.e. does your sheet have different Interior colors before that or is this exclusively used to mark cells as randomized?

Comment: And what should happen, if the color is already blue?

Comment: Ok I think I got your question from the `edit` clarification.

Comment: @Spurious: the sheet is empty and the way I know that the code works is if 5 different cells are filled with the blue color. IF the cell is already marked/filled, then it should choose another cell, for instance give it an offset of (1,0)

Comment: I must say you're making this awfully difficult. If your only objective is to get those five cells colored then there are easier ways.

Comment: Is this homework?  Looks like the same Question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38642683/vba-set-up-a-2d-array-in-vba-with-random-cells-filled-with-color?rq=1

Comment: @Spurious: I copied your code, it works great so far no matter how many times I tried to randomize them, thank you. It's not about filling 5 cells, it's a much more dynamic code that should be able to work on a 500x500 matrix and fill 1000 cells, I just used a simple example to visualize it.

Comment: @ S Meaden it is a final project in a VBA course in uni, my question is just the beginning of a much more complex code which I'm working on, and I only ask questions that I absolutely have no idea how to utilize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the cells you use in a `Collection` and remove them as you fill the random cells:

```
Sub FillRandomCells(targetRange As Range, numberOfCells As Long)

    ' populate collection of unique cells
    Dim c As Range
    Dim targetCells As New Collection

    ' make sure arguments make sense
    If numberOfCells > targetRange.Cells.Count Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError, "FillRandomCells()", _
                "Number of cells to be changed can not exceed number of cells in range"
    End If

    For Each c In targetRange.Cells
        targetCells.Add c
    Next

    ' now pick random 5
    Dim i As Long, randomIndex As Long
    Dim upperbound As Long
    Dim lowerbound As Long

    For i = 1 To numberOfCells
        lowerbound = 1                 ' collections start with 1
        upperbound = targetCells.Count ' changes as we are removing cells we used

        randomIndex = Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
        Set c = targetCells(randomIndex)
        targetCells.Remove randomIndex ' remove so we don't use it again!

        c.Interior.Color = 5           ' do what you need to do here
    Next

End Sub

Sub testFillRandomCells()
    FillRandomCells ActiveSheet.[a1:t20], 5
    FillRandomCells ActiveSheet.[b25:f30], 3
End Sub
```

EDIT: Changed to make the target range and number of changed cells configurable as arguments to a function. Also added error checking (always do that!).

Comment: Thank you @Logan Reed, I will try this, although Spurious's code also worked. Thank you two for your codes, you've been very helpful. Much appreciated.

Comment: @vbmolec Spurious's code will definitely work. My solution avoids the need to check for duplicates entirely, which is slightly more efficient. You also should avoid `Splitting` that array on every loop iteration -- it is highly inefficient (do it once in the beginning and keep as a variable).

Comment: I think I would replace my existing code with yours, it really looks more efficient. I have a question though: I need to make it dynamic - the user chooses the dimensions which are stored in 2 variables, and the code should work only within those 2 numbers: 100x100 or 15x15 and so, how do I make your code more dynamic in this line: For Each c In ActiveSheet.[a1:t20].Cells ' 20x20 range ?

Comment: @vbmolec You can use any `Range` object in there - just make sure number of cells to change is less than the number of cells in a target range. See updated in the example.

Comment: This code is better than mine, I deleted mine due to the fact that is not a super clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not build a list of random numbers and place in a Scripting.Dictionary, one can use the Dictionary's Exist method to detect duplicates, loop through until you have enough then you can enter your colouring code confident that you have a unique list.

Comment: I am not sure why everyone resorts to `Scripting.Dictionary` as the only difference between that and a standard `Collection` is that you can't retrieve the key (after you put in the value). Everything else can be achieved with standard VBA methods (not built-in, but you can write those yourselves).